# libproject/google-play-services_lib for eclipse

Tags: android, google-play-services, eclipse-adt

[image]

Copy the library project at /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/ to the location where you maintain your Android app projects.

Comment: What was the question?

Comment: The question is: where's libproject folder? I have same isssue..

Answer (score 1):

You'll find them in /extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms, if you also updated Google Repository through the SDK Manager.

The individual libraries are in aar format, so you'll have to extract the jar yourself, if that's what you're after.